# Integrating the derivative of a function

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I have this question of calculus, my answer was **d** but my teacher told me it was wrong. What am I not seeing? What would be the answer and why:

If $f$ is a continuous function and if $F'(x) = f(x)$ for all real numbers $x$, then $\int_{1}^3 f(2x)dx$ is

a) $2F(3) − 2F(1)$
b) $0.5F(3) − 0.5F(1)$
c) $2F(6) − 2F(2)$
d) $F(6) − F(2)$
e) $0.5F(6) − 0.5F(2)$

Comment: Hint: make a u-substitution.

Comment: It will be u = 2x -> f(u) and when I'm Integrating F(u) -> F(2x)|3,1 but that is wrong

Comment: Wait, whit u = 2x, du = 2. It will be 2F(2x)|3,1, Am I correct?

Comment: Please tell us how you reached the conclusion d).

Comment: I integrate normally, but I already saw my error, and with the answer from @Dhanvi Sreenivasan I finished understanding the u-substitution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$I = \int_1^3f(2x)dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{2}^{6}f(u)du$$

If $u=2x$, the limits will double $x =1 \to u=2, x=3 \to u = 6$, and $du = 2dx$

Using fundamental theorem of calculus

$$I = 0.5F(6)-0.5F(2)$$

Comment: Man, why do you change the limits? I don't undestand that

Comment: The limits are for x. When you change the variable, the limits have to be written in the new variable terms, since we are now integrating with respect to $u$. As an exercise, use an online graphing calculator (desmos), and try it yourself - consider a function whose antiderivative you know, and see what exactly is going on

Comment: Thank you very much @Dhanvi Sreenivasan, you are the best!!!